# ¿Cómo puedo calcular el porcentaje?

Tags: r, r-dplyr

Tengo una tabla que va de la siguiente forma

```
dx<-data.frame("clinica"<-as.factor(c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B")),
"Diabetes"<-c(0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1),
"Hipertension"<-c(1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0))
```

Necesito calcular el total de casos con diabetes y hipertensión para cada clinica y el porcentaje por clinica. Lo he intentado de la siguiente forma

```
 

    df5<-df %>%
      group_by(clinica)%>%
      summarize(Diabetes=sum(Diabetes), Hipertension=sum(Hipertension))
    
    df_5<-df5 %>% 
      pivot_longer(c("Diabetes","Hipertension"), names_to = "Comorbilidades", values_to = "valor")
      
    df_5<-df_5 %>% 
      group_by(sede_dx)%>%
      mutate(per=paste0(round(valor/sum(valor)*100, 2), "%")) %>% 
           ungroup
```

El problema es que calcula el porcentaje de la suma de las dos enfermedades y no del total de casos, y como una persona puede tener las dos enfermedades, pues me da un resultado erróneo, les agradezco mucho la ayuda

Comment: ¡Bienvenida a [es.so]! Te sugiero que hagas el [tour] (e incluso ganarás tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)), leas [ask] y en lo posible mejores el título de tu pregunta, para hacerla más específica.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que lo que buscas es algo así:

```
df %>%
  group_by(clinica)%>%
  summarize(Diabetes=sum(Diabetes)/n()*100, 
            Hipertension=sum(Hipertension)/n()*100) %>% 
  pivot_longer(c("Diabetes","Hipertension"), names_to = "Comorbilidades", values_to = "valor")

# A tibble: 4 x 3
  clinica Comorbilidades valor
  <fct>   <chr>          <dbl>
1 A       Diabetes          50
2 A       Hipertension      50
3 B       Diabetes          75
4 B       Hipertension      75
```

Al agrupar por `clinica` podemos obtener el total de casos del grupo mediante `n()`, con lo que ya es fácil llegar al porcentaje de la enfermedad por cantidad de casos.

Comment: Siiii, muchas gracias, ven pero y si necesito que me de tanto el porcentaje como el numero?

Comment: Guardas la solución de Patricio en un objeto, por ejemplo df1. Luego duplicas el código, pero sin dividir por el número de casos, y lo guardas por ejemplo en un objeto df2. Luego realizar un merge de ambos, cuidando los nombres. df <- merge(df1, df2)